# Данные по промежутку времени

Tags: mysql, sql

Есть таблица с данными типо: айди, айдиобъекта, состояние, дата. В ней сохраняются данные при изменении состояния, если в течении дня состояние меняется, то оно заноситься в таблицу. Как получить данные по всем данным за промежуток времени я понял, но мне надо если изменений состояния в этом промежутке не происходило то взять последнее состояние перед этим промежутком?

Пример: У нас есть 5 объектов, у первого объекта запись за 1 день с состоянием к примеру за 01.05, которое не менялось до 04.05, есть второй объект у которого есть 4 записи к примеру 01.05, 03.05,04.05 и 04.05. у остальных объектов есть записи за каждый день начиная с 01.05, если брать все записи за 03.05 первого объекта нету, но я бы хотел получить его состояние за 01.05 и добавить к выдаче.

Comment: То есть та же задача, но без ограничения снизу.

Comment: Скорее похоже на то что стартовую дату нужно сместить до появления записей. Однако просто изменить стартовую дату не сильно катит, так как получится что я получу избыточные данные по объекту который попадёт в заданный промежуток

Comment: *получится что я получу избыточные данные* С какого это перепугу-то?

Comment: Когда задаете вопрос, необходимо предоставить "Минимальный воспроизводимый пример".
Для справки: Как создать минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример
https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Для вашего сценария это означает следующее:
(1) DDL и образец вставки данных, т.е. CREATE table(s) плюс операторы INSERT, в SQL.
(2) Что вам нужно сделать, т.е. логика и ваш SQL код пытающийся ее реализовать.
(3) Ожидаемый результат на основе примера данных в #1 выше.
(4) Ваша база данных (СУБД) и ее версия.

Comment: @lektorO_o Попробуйте сформулировать [в вопросе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/1277983/edit), комментерий служат для уточнений, а не для формулировки самого вопроса.